# Segment raw time series into chunks

Tags: matlab

I have written code in Matlab to read data from CSV file and store it in an array the file contain many rows and 4 main columns (time, x,y,z). the time is then divided into segments of 10 seconds. i have calculated the start and finish time for each segment, now I want to get the x,y,and z-data into each segment. can you guys help me please?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: hi mate,wahwahwah , I have divided the time in the array into 10 seconds , now i want the data which is in the second, third and fourth columns of every ten seconds in one segment . i hope you get what i mean . regards.